# Unable to install GNOME shell extensions using GNOME Tweaks in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.04, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I am unable to manually install GNOME shell extensions downloaded from the official [site](https://extensions.gnome.org/) using the `gnome-tweak tool` as the option for installing new shell extension is missing in `gnome-tweak-tool`(which was there in previous versions).

I have installed both `gnome-tweak-tool` and `gnome-shell-extensions` by running the following commands,

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

Is the ordinary procedure has changed in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? If so, could anyone please specify the new procedures to be followed?